# Naive Suffix Tree implementation using recursion

Tags: c++

This is my implementation of the suffix tree using the `O(n^2)` naive algorithm recursively. It is also my first big project in which I've used all the knowledge I have acquired about C++ so far. I would appreciate any advice on how to improve my code and make it compatible with the modern C++ best practices.

SuffixTree.h

```
#ifndef SUFFIX_TREE_H
#define SUFFIX_TREE_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

namespace trie
{
    typedef std::size_t size_type;

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    // bidirectional map to create one-to-one mapping between the alphabet of input string and it's rank in `BiMap`
    class BiMap
    {
    public:
        void insert(const T1& a, const T2& b);          // insert and create a mapping between `a` and `b`
        void generateKeys(const std::string& text);     // find unique alphabets in `text` and call `insert` with their respective ranks
        T2 retrieve(const T1& key);                     // return the rank when passed it's corresponding alphabet
        T1 retrieve(const T2& key);                     // return the alphabet when passed it's corresponding rank
        size_type getSize();                            // return total mappings created (used to specify how many children a node must have)
        void print();                                   // print the mappings
    private:
        std::map<T1, T2*> map1_;                        // alphabet saved as key with it's value pointing to it's corresponding rank which is key of `map2_`
        std::map<T2, T1*> map2_;                        // rank saved as key with it's value pointing to it's corresponding alphabet which is key of `map1_`
    };

    // node of the suffix tree
    struct Node
    {
        Node(size_type id, int length, int size);
        size_type id_;                                  // represents the position in text where suffix represented by this node begins
        int length_;                                    // length of the substring encapsulated by the given node (only for internal nodes). -1 means it's a leaf.
        std::vector<Node*> children_;                   // `BiMap::getSize()` number of children for each node.
    };

    class SuffixTree
    {
    public:
        SuffixTree(const std::string& text = "");       // constructor for text passed from main
        SuffixTree(const std::ifstream& file);          // constructor for text passed from input file
        Node* insert(Node* current, size_type id, int length = 0);      // recursive function to insert node with id = `id` called on root
        void constructTree();                           // loop over all suffixes of `text_` and call `insert` on each
        void printSuffixes();                           // print suffixes inorder
        void printSuffixes(Node* current);              // called by above function
        void printInorder();                            // print all nodes in suffix tree inorder
        void printInorder(Node* current);               // called by above function
        void deleteTree(Node* current);                 // recursive deleter called by the destructor
        ~SuffixTree();
    private:
        std::string text_;              // saves the input text
        BiMap<char, size_type> map_;    // maps alphabet of `text_`
        Node *root_;                    // constructed as soon as `SuffixTree` object is created
    };
}

#include "SuffixTree.inl"

#endif
```

SuffixTree.inl

```
#include "SuffixTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::insert(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
    auto itr1 = map1_.emplace(t1, nullptr).first;
    auto itr2 = map2_.emplace(t2, nullptr).first;
    map1_[itr1->first] = (T2*) &(itr2->first);          // I know this is dangerous but once built, I only use it for reading.
    map2_[itr2->first] = (T1*) &(itr1->first);          // This is the simplest BiMap implementation I came up with.
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::generateKeys(const std::string& text)
{
    std::set<char> S;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
        S.insert(text[i]);

    size_type rank = 0;
    for (auto itr = S.cbegin(); itr != S.cend(); ++itr)
        insert(*itr, rank++);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::retrieve(const T1& key)
{
    if (map1_.find(key) == map1_.cend())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return *map1_[key];
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::retrieve(const T2& key)
{
    if (map2_.find(key) == map2_.cend())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return *map2_[key];
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
trie::size_type trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::getSize()
{
    return map1_.size() | map2_.size();
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::print()
{
    for (typename std::map<T1, T2*>::const_iterator itr = map1_.cbegin(), end = map1_.cend(); itr != end; ++itr)
        std::cout << itr->first << " -> " << *itr->second << std::endl;
}

trie::Node::Node(size_type id, int length, int size)
    : id_(id), length_(length), children_(size, nullptr)
{

}

trie::SuffixTree::SuffixTree(const std::string& text)
    : text_(text)
{
    map_.generateKeys(text_);
    map_.print();
    root_ = new Node(-1, 0, map_.getSize());        // `id` and `length` of root node don't matter as they're never accessed
}

trie::SuffixTree::SuffixTree(const std::ifstream& file)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << file.rdbuf();         // redirect file buffer to string stream
    text_ = ss.str();           // copy the string from ss to `text_`
    map_.generateKeys(text_);
    map_.print();
    root_ = new Node(-1, 0, map_.getSize());
}

trie::Node* trie::SuffixTree::insert(Node* current, size_type id, int length)
 {
    if (current == nullptr)                 // return the leaf to link it to it's parent
        return new Node(id, -1, map_.getSize());

    if (current->length_ == -1)             // if `current` is a leaf
    {
        size_type i = id + length;          // `length` is used to keep track of how many matches we have done so far in the path till here.
                                            // Hard to explain this one. You'll have to look at the insertion of `a~`, the 2nd last suffix in `banana~`, to understand it right.
        size_type j = current->id_ + length;
        while (text_[i] == text_[j])        // match the substring represented by this node (using j) with the substring starting at position `id` in text
        {
            length += 1;
            i += 1;
            j += 1;
        }

        /*
            Link of `current` with it's parent is broken and a new node is inserted in it's place whose `length` represents
            the substring we have matched so far in the path from `root` till `current`.
            The "broken" node, `current`, is rejoined at the correct position in the `children` of the new node.
            The "correct position" is determined by the first char which the rest of the string `current` represents (where text_[i] and text_[j] are not equal).
            Once that's done, continue the recursive insertion procedure from `text_[i]`.
        */
        Node *temp = new Node(current->id_, length, map_.getSize());
        size_type rankJ = map_.retrieve(text_[j]);
        temp->children_[rankJ] = current;
        size_type rankI = map_.retrieve(text_[i]);
        temp->children_[rankI] = insert(temp->children_[rankI], id, length);
        return temp;        // `temp` has to be returned as now it is the new child of the parent instead of `current`.
    }
    else                                    // if `current` is an internal node
    {
        size_type i = id + length;
        size_type j = current->id_ + length;
        size_type limit = current->length_-length;
        while (limit && text_[i] == text_[j])
        {
            length += 1;
            i += 1;
            j += 1;
            limit -= 1;
        }
        size_type rankI = map_.retrieve(text_[i]);
        current->children_[rankI] = insert(current->children_[rankI], id, length);      // if everything is matching so far, we continue down
        return current;
    }
}

void trie::SuffixTree::constructTree()
{
    for (size_type i = 0; i < text_.size(); ++i)
    {
        size_type rank = map_.retrieve(text_[i]);
        root_->children_[rank] = insert(root_->children_[rank], i);
    }
}

void trie::SuffixTree::printSuffixes()
{
    printSuffixes(root_);
}

void trie::SuffixTree::printSuffixes(Node* current)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return;
    if (current->length_ == -1)
        std::cout << text_.substr(current->id_) << std::endl;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < current->children_.size(); ++i)
        printSuffixes(current->children_[i]);
}

void trie::SuffixTree::printInorder()
{
    printInorder(root_);
}

void trie::SuffixTree::printInorder(Node* current)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < current->children_.size(); ++i)
        printInorder(current->children_[i]);
    std::cout << current->id_ << ' ' << current->length_ << std::endl;
}

void trie::SuffixTree::deleteTree(Node* current)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < current->children_.size(); ++i)
        deleteTree(current->children_[i]);
    delete current;
}

trie::SuffixTree::~SuffixTree()
{
    deleteTree(root_);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SuffixTree.h"

int main()
{
    trie::SuffixTree Tree("banana~");
    Tree.constructTree();
    Tree.printSuffixes();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't `#include "SuffixTree.h"` in `SuffixTree.inl`. Since the `.inl` file is included in the header below the class definitions, they will be available to the implementation code. Including the header again would be a circular dependency.

---

Your compiler should give you various warnings about converting from `std::size_t` to `int`, and comparing signed / unsigned numbers.

These can be fixed by changing the length and size arguments / members in the `Node` class to be `size_type`.

Using `-1` for invalid values should still work ok.

---

**`BiMap`:**

```
T2 retrieve(const T1& key);
T1 retrieve(const T2& key);
```

It would be better for these functions to have different names.

- It's much more difficult to understand the code because we have to look at the type of the key being passed in to see which value is being retrieved.
- If `T1` and `T2` happen to be the same type this won't compile due to ambiguity.

It looks like we only use the first version of `retrieve` anyway. Do we really need the bidirectional look up?

---

Does `generateKeys()` work if called a second time? If not, it would be best to use the `BiMap` constructor to take the text and pass it to `generateKeys()`, and make `generateKeys()` private.

`insert()` could also be private, since it doesn't look like it's intended to be called from outside the class.

---

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
trie::size_type trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::getSize()
{
    return map1_.size() | map2_.size();
}
```

Uh... This doesn't seem correct. If the intention is to return the maximum, we could use `std::max(map1_.size(), map2_.size())`? It would be reasonable to `assert` that the values are the same, and just return either of them.

---

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void trie::BiMap<T1, T2>::print()
{
    for (typename std::map<T1, T2*>::const_iterator itr = map1_.cbegin(), end = map1_.cend(); itr != end; ++itr)
        std::cout << itr->first << " -> " << *itr->second << std::endl;
}
```

A range-based for loop with `auto` would be much clearer:

```
for (auto const& i : map1_)
    std::cout << i.first << " -> " << i.second << std::endl;
```

---

Member functions that don't change member state should be `const`:

```
    T2 retrieve(const T1& key) const;
    T1 retrieve(const T2& key) const;
    size_type getSize() const;
    void print() const;
```

---

**`Node`:**

```
    size_type id_;                                  // represents the position in text where suffix represented by this node begins
    int length_;                                    // length of the substring encapsulated by the given node (only for internal nodes). -1 means it's a leaf.
```

IIRC, the special character at the end of the string (`~`) is a means of marking the end nodes. If we use a length placeholder of `-1` to mark the end nodes, I don't think we need the placeholder character (or vice versa).

Both `id_` and `length_` seem to be serving dual purposes. For an external node, `id_` is the suffix start index, but for an internal node it doesn't mean anything. For an external node, `length_` is `-1`, but for an internal node, it's the string length for this segment.

This is quite complicated. It would be neater to *always* store the relevant indices for the string segment (and probably easier to use the suffix tree for various purposes later).

We can add a `std::optional<size_type>` member to store the suffix index. If this is set, we know we're at an end node (so we avoid the need for the special character or the alternate meaning for `length_`).

---

**`SuffixTree`:**

```
SuffixTree(const std::string& text = "");
SuffixTree(const std::ifstream& file);
```

We should read input from the file outside of the `SuffixTree` class and call the other constructor. The `SuffixTree` shouldn't care about file input.

The default value for `text` seems rather unnecessary.

---

```
trie::SuffixTree Tree("banana~");
Tree.constructTree();
```

We can call `constructTree` in the constructor.

---

```
root_ = new Node(size_type(-1), 0, map_.getSize());
```

We should use `std::unique_ptr`s to store the nodes, rather than doing manual memory management.

---

```
    size_type rankJ = map_.retrieve(text_[j]);
    temp->children_[rankJ] = ...
```

We could abstract this (finding a relevant child node by character) into a separate helper function (e.g. `getChild(temp, text_[j]) = ...`).

---

Several functions could be private, as they can't sensibly be called from outside the class:

```
    Node* insert(Node* current, size_type id, int length = 0);
    void constructTree();
    void printSuffixes(Node* current);              // called by above function
    void printInorder(Node* current);               // called by above function
    void deleteTree(Node* current);
```

Again, any member functions that don't change member state (e.g. printing) should be `const`.

---

For the `insert` function, if we have C++14, we can use [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) to find the point at which the inserted string differs from the node. (It's awkward to use before C++14 because we had to depend on the second range provided being shorter than the first).

---